# Как записать шаблон md5(пароль_таймштамп)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, авторизация, axios, md5

у меня проблема с шаблоном md5, в документации к API написано что по его нужно указать в параметре авторизационной строки, указывая его я не всё равно не могу авторизоваться.
Вот часть документации к API:
Аутентификация запросов происходит за счет авторизационной строки, которая передается в параметре заголовка X-Auth.
Значение X-Auth формируется по следующему шаблону: md5(пароль_таймштамп)
Таймштамп представляет собой текущую дату UTC с точностью до дня в формате год, месяц, день без разделителей.
Пароль и таймштамп разделяются символом подчеркивания.
Пример: md5("password_20230821")
В случае, если авторизационная строка сформирована некорректно, будет возвращен HTTP код 401
Вот мой код:

```
import $host from './index'

let config = {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth": md5("Valantis_20240225"),
    }
  }


export const getStore  = async (products) => {
    try {
        const response = await $host.post(products, config)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        // alert(error)
    }
}
```

Может как то по другому нужно записать, не уверен, помогите пожалуйста.

Ожидал получить авторизацию.
Я уверен что

```
let config = {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth": md5("Valantis_20240225"),
    }
  }
```

правильная запись, а вот с самим значением не уверен, писал и без ,md5, и без скобок, и по разному.

Comment: Эти вопросы надо адресовать авторам апи, которым вы пользуетесь(кстати вы даже не указали, что это, хоть бы ссылку на документацию)

Comment: Как минимум сразу же неочевидно, md5 должен быть в формате hex, base64 или base64url

Comment: Самое основное из документации я указал, остальное там это методы и всё, вот ссылка на сайт api откуда я должен брать товары и авторизоваться: http://api.valantis.store:40000/

Comment: Насчёт формата я не знаю, я могу перевести Valantis_20240225 в эти форматы, но что потом с ними делать я не знаю

Comment: Я попробовал захешировать через CryptoJS в md5 как вы сказали, получилось вот что: 70e9e15f52c7209ab6b6f80b795aa4f2
Я его так же передал, но оно до сих пор не авторизует

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за помощь, решил проблему тем что просто обратился через обычный fetch а не axios.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

const password = 'Valantis';
const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-').join('');
const data = `${password}_${timestamp}`;

const authorizationString = CryptoJS.MD5(data).toString();;

export const getStore = async () => {
await fetch("http://api.valantis.store:40000/", {
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-Auth': authorizationString
},
body: JSON.stringify(
{
action: 'get_ids'
}
),

```
    }).then( res => {
       res.json().then(results => 
        {let result = results
            if (result !== undefined) {
                console.log(result)
                return result
            }
         })
    }
        
     );
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Да, ты прав, твоя запись правильна, `md5` - это шифрование, я уверен что в заголовке `"X-Auth": md5("Valantis_20240225")` заложен вызов функции кеширования, есть пакет `md5`, найди и скачай эту библиотеку, также таймштамп советую сделать динамическим!

```
import $host from './index'
import md5 from "md5";

const stamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,"");

const hash = md5(`${password}_${stamp }`);

let config = {
    headers: {
      "X-Auth": hash ,
    }
  }


export const getStore  = async (products) => {
        try {
        const response = await $host.post(products, config)
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        // alert(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятна суть ответа